# How to navigate to an activity from a notification with FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications

So I have this foreground service notification and when the user taps that I want to navigate to one of my activities. OK, seems like you just have to supply a PendingIntent to the notification builder.

OK, that seems to work fine...except I don't want to add more identical entries to the activity stack when the user taps more than once.

Use the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP...OK, so now I have something like this:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyAwesomeActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, NotificationChannel.DEFAULT_CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_info)
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText("Some nice text here.")
            .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
            .build();
```

Looks nice...except it doesn't work. Repeated taps just add new entries to the stack and pressing the back button shows the same activity several times. Not nice.

How do I make it work properly?

Comment: Care to share why you downvoted this one? As someone new to Android, I put this one here for others who might go the same way.

Comment: OK looks like I messed up the code part in the question...should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I didn't rtfm quite enough.

I found a working solution on the oficial Android documentation page:
https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation

Revised version that works:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyAwesomeActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(intent);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, NotificationChannel.DEFAULT_CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_info)
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText("Some nice text here.")
            .setContentIntent(stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
            .build();
```